# How to remove Duplicated values in People search box webpart Fast Search 2010?

Tags: 2010, search, fast-search, people-search, fast-for-sharepoint

when i am search on `PeopleResults.aspx`page at that bind duplicated values on People search box webpart. i am checking every properties on that webpart.but nothing to worked.

Here is screenshot : [image]

page working as expected with results. but issues only duplicated value.any body have Idea whats problem??

Comment: If you index a person with a real firstname, lastname and fullname in the user profile (double check in UPS). Does it still render wrongly?

Comment: yes.still i am facing same problem.not getting any clues regrading this.can you pls help?

Comment: Try to create a new search center and see if that one shows it correct.

Comment: hi,I m create new server and seem to exist same issue in my new search center.For temp i removing duplicate value using javascript.I know that is not current solution.and i want to knw why this causes. what wrong in my `Fast Query SSA`?

Comment: It's weird indeed. What if you create a regular SSA, index user profiles, set up a enterprise search center, and test it. Meaning, do it without the FAST Query SSA. They should work just the same, but you could try. I would also like to see a screenshot with a person with a real firstname/lastname.

Comment: hi.i am new comer in fast search.I havent much experience.if you give me some guide its better for me.Can you solve my this probm in my [Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47290/can-i-used-people-search-core-webpart-and-search-core-webpart-in-same-page-fast)?