# Can I used People search core webpart and Search Core Webpart in Same page Fast Search?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

in my `result.aspx` i have used almost webpart like SearchPagingWebPart,CoreResultWebpart,Search Actionlink webpart, etc..

I am used PoepleSearchCoreResult wepbart in that page as People Matches.

i.e : searching url is `results.aspx?k=administrator&s=All Sites` so result coming perfect in Search Core Result Wepbart and People Search Core Result Wepbart but other webpart like SearchPagingWebPart result showing based on `People Search Core Result Wepbart` and also missing Search Action Link webpart(Sort By filter dropdownlist).

[image]

In screenshot.after removing People Search core result webpart All the webpart coming Perfect. any one can you help me how to prevent this?

[image]